# Drawing line chart in angularjs with json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, charts, linechart

I have json data with multiple companies like:

`[
    {
        "company": "Abc",
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2014-06-03",
                "price": 61.5
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-06-04",
                "price": 42.9
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-06-05",
                "price": 63.7
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-06-06",
                "price": 73.5
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-06-09",
                "price": 54.25
            },
            }]},
{
        "company": "Xyz",
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2015-01-21",
                "price": 2453.0
            },
            {
                "date": "2015-01-22",
                "price": 2434.8
            },
            {
                "date": "2015-01-23",
                "price": 2537.8
            },
            {
                "date": "2015-01-27",
                "price": 2418.0
            }]}`

There will be more companies like this in the data. I want to draw line charts with this, multiple lines, one graph. I'm pretty clueless on how to go about this. I followed some docs like nvd3 but could not make sense out of it. How to do this?

Comment: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. and not really helpfull

Comment: It's serialized by drf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used angular-nvd3 for the charting, worked fine. Thanks for the responses though.

Answer (score 1):

Simple request on Google, should be good for what you need:

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/